# Prolog factorial predicate

Tags: prolog, factorial, failure-slice

I have a factorial predicate`fact(N,F)`, where either `N` or `F` or both are bounded to a number.

For example I can have `fact(3,F)` or `fact(N,6)`.
Here is my predicate, which works but I don't really understand how. I used `trace` but still have problems understanding it.

```
fact(0,1).
fact(N,F) :-
        fact(N1,F1),
        N is N1 + 1,
        F is N * F1.
```

Comment: You can also manually "step" through it: `fact(3, F)` doesn't match `fact(0, 1)` (since 3 and 0 are not unifiable), so Prolog will match the next clause `fact(N, F)` with `N = 3`. It then calls `fact(N1, F1)` coming up with `N1 = 0` and `F1 = 1` per the first clause again, and so on. Note that, after finding the solution, it tries to find more and does not terminate, causing a stack overflow.

Comment: I'm curious: how did you go about writing this predicate if you don't know how it works?

Comment: @lurker: That's very understandable: Another version might have produced an instantiation error.

Comment: @lurker: Well, I started from this version: `factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, F):-
        N > 0,
        N1 is N - 1,
        factorial(N1, F1),
        F is N * F1.`, and tried until I got that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to go through your program step-by-step to understand what's going on. This will be very slow indeed, and quite unreliable. Or, you can instead let Prolog do (part of) the work. So the idea is to modify the program a bit and then look what Prolog thinks about it.

This is what I see when I look at your program - this is called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)

```
fact(0,1) :- false.
fact(N,F) :-
        fact(N1,F1), false,
        N is N1 + 1,
        F is N * F1.
```

When will this fragment terminate? Look at the remaining visible part! The `N` only occurs once in the head: nobody is interested in the first argument! Same for the `F`. Therefore: No matter what arguments you have, this program will not terminate. **And thus the same holds for your original program!**

In the original version this wasn't that clear. Watch out:

```
?- fact(29,F).
   F = 8841761993739701954543616000000
```

At first this looks nice, but if you ask for the next answer (with SPACE or `;`), you end up looping, i.e. waiting for an answer that never comes. Worse, false queries loop right away:

```
?- fact(29,1).
   loops.
```

So how can you find these problems, without understanding precisely what is going on? This is what **`false`** is for. A goal that is never true. If you add it like `fact(29,F), false.` you will never be distracted by beautiful answers.

Why have you put all your arithmetics at the end? I suspect because you got some errors before. There is an easy way out to avoid all such errors:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

You can now write `#=` instead of `is`, and you need some restriction like `N #>= 1`. Can I leave you there?

Comment: you write "No matter what arguments you have, this program will not terminate. And thus the same holds for your original program!" and then you immediately give an example call for which the original program does terminate. (just a side note)

Comment: @Will: Please continue reading! To quote: *At first this looks nice, but if you ask for the next answer (with SPACE or ;), you end up looping*. So at first you have the impression that this program terminates, but by hitting the SPACE bar you see that this is not the case.

Comment: @Will: are your corrections RP? In any case `*LOOPS*` is just invalid syntax...

Comment: re: `** LOOPS **`, *because* it is invalid syntax it is immediately clear that it is a meta-comment. `loops.` is a valid syntax, and thus confusing. what is RP please?

Comment: [RP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)

Comment: Note that what we have here is an answer *description*. So it is as much a meta-comment as *any* answer is. Just think of an answer `L = [_E]`. It needs some quantification. &ct